# How to read file names of items in a Zipped Folder? Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to read the names of files within a zipped folder on Google Drive.
From there I will create new folders using a trimmed portion of the file name.

My below codes works, however the way I am reading the filename is to unzip it first, copy it to a temp location and read the filename.  This function runs pretty slowly, my zipped file has 800+ files.  Each one with a unique filename.

The code below first checks in the folder destination if a folder with yesterdays date as the title exists, if not it creates one.  Then it checks a set folder for a zip file who's title contains yesterdays date.  After finding it, it will loop through the zip file and extract each file within (jpegs) save them to a folder 'Temp' and retrieve a substring of the name.  Then it checks the appropriate date folder to see if it has any folders that exist with the filename substring, if not it creates a new folder.

```
function CreateNewImageFolder() {
  const optionalArgs={supportsAllDrives: true};                                              // enables support for shared drive
  const timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();                                              // returns script timezone
  const afId = 'archivefolderID'                                           // Image Drive "Image_Archive" Folder ID
  const aDest = DriveApp.getFolderById(afId);                                                // returns 'Archive source' folder "Image_Archive"
  const op20Id = 'fixedfolderW/allfilenames'                                         // Image Drive "Folder that contains all possible filenames" Folder ID
  const op20 = DriveApp.getFolderById(op20Id);                                               // returns OP20 folder
  const tId = 'tempfolderID'                                            // Image Drive "temp" Folder ID
  const temp = DriveApp.getFolderById(tId);                                                  // returns OP20 folder "temp"
  
  var yday = Utilities.formatDate(GetYesterday(1), timezone, "MM-dd");                       // returns yesterdays date for file name search
  var yyear = Utilities.formatDate(GetYesterday(1), timezone, "yyyy-MM-dd");                     // returns yesterdays date + year for folder name search
    Logger.log("Yesterday: %s", yday);

//// Checks for existing Date Folder and creates a new one if not exist ///
  var datefold = aDest.searchFolders("title contains '"+yyear+"'");                           // search aDest for existing date folder
    if (datefold.hasNext()===true) {                                                        
      while (datefold.hasNext()) {
        var dfolder = datefold.next();
        Logger.log("Folder %s already exists", dfolder.getName());
      }
    } else{
        var dfolder=aDest.createFolder(yyear);                                                // if not exist create new folder in aDest
          Logger.log("New Date Folder Name: %s", dfolder.getName());
      }
    var dfoldId = dfolder.getId();
    var vDest = DriveApp.getFolderById(dfoldId);
      Logger.log("New Folder Destination: %s", vDest.getName());

//// loops through ZIP file iterator ////
  var zfi = op20.searchFiles("title contains '"+yday+"'");                                    // search op20 folder for Yesterdays Zip File 'file iterator'
    while (zfi.hasNext()){                                                                    // loops through ZIP file iterator
      var file = zfi.next();                                                                  // every loop sets active file to next
        Logger.log("Zip Folder: %s", file.getName());
      var fileBlob = file.getBlob();                                                         // get file blob
      fileBlob.setContentType("application/zip");                                             
      var unZippedfile = Utilities.unzip(fileBlob);                                          // unzipped file iterator

  //// loops all blob elements ////
      for (i=0; i<unZippedfile.length; i++) {                                                
        var uzf = temp.createFile(unZippedfile[i]);                                          // creates upzipped file in "temp" folder
        var fileName = uzf.getName().substring(0, 17);                                           // trims Image name string to first 17 characters
          Logger.log("unzipped File Name: %s", fileName);

    //// Checks for existing Folder and creates a new one if not exist ////    
        var vfold = vDest.searchFolders("title contains '"+fileName+"'");                      // search vDest for existing folder
        if (vfold.hasNext()===true) {    
          while (vfold.hasNext()) {
          var vfolder = vfold.next();
          Logger.log("Folder %s already exists", vfolder.getName());
          }
        } else{
          var vfolder=vDest.createFolder(fileName);                                                // if not exist create new folder in aDest
            Logger.log("New Folder Name: %s", vfolder.getName());
          }
        uzf.setTrashed(true);
      }
    }
}
```

> Simple Example
> Zipped Folder Located at:
>
> > Root > Image_Archive > Station > Camera > Date > 'zippedfolderName_2022_10_23'
> >
> > > zipped folder contains several image files all starting with unique 17 character #.  ex:  1ABCXXXXXXXXXXXX1

> Desired Output
>
> > Root > Image_Archive > New_Folder (named with yesterdays date) > New_Folder (named using 17 character # ex: 1ABCXXXXXXXXXXXX1)

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample zip file for testing your script? And, can I ask you about the file size of your zip file?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot supply a sample of the zip file.  I can tell you that each zip file is named with the current date at the end of the filename and the .jpg files within all have a similar name with unique 17 characters at the start of the filename.  The file size is approximately 40 MB.

Comment: No problem.  However it is not resolved. As stated below, it does not appear to be possible.  I will attempt a different approach by not using a zip file at all.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `However it is not resolved. As stated below, it does not appear to be possible. I will attempt a different approach by not using a zip file at all.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide your sample input and output situations you expect as the images? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I have edited the question with a section explaining the folder structure and desired result

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. I would like to confirm my understanding of your question. In your ZIP file, the files are directly put without subfolders. And, all file names of all files are like `1ABCXXXXXXXXXXXX1`. And, you want to retrieve all files in the ZIP file, and create all files to the specific folder of `(new folder named with current date)`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes no subfolders within the zip file.  With this script I am only trying to create new folders using the 17 character filename within the same root directory.  Unzipping the actual files to these new locations would be done with another function.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About the ZIP file `zippedfolderName_2022_10_24`, in this case, the file ID can be directly used? Or, it is required to search the file by the filename every run? And, can I ask you about the detail of `new folder named with current date`? By the way, the number of ZIP files is only one every run?

Comment: This would be run against new ZIP files created every day. Prior to creating the folders using the Image File names, I would check and create a fold with the Current Date for file organization purposes. To use the ZIP file ID I would probably have to search the name to return the ID.  This runs using 1 ZIP file to extract the names of the files within and use those names to create new folders within the newly created Current Date Folder.  Ultimately another function will run on all other camera ZIP files to organize the images based on the date and that 17 character #.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `To use the ZIP file ID I would probably have to search the name to return the ID.`, in your situation,  `2022_10_24` of `zippedfolderName_2022_10_24` is changed every day. And, when a script is run, only one ZIP file retrieved from the filename like `zippedfolderName_yyyy_MM_dd` is required to be processed. Is my understanding correct? And, about `new folder named with current date`, I cannot still understand. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I deeply apologize that I'm trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249023/discussion-between-aarons-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 1):

**Listing ZIP files from Google Drive**

After reviewing all documentation regarding Drive and how the apps script function, you would always need to unzip it in order to be able to view the data and files from Drive.

Being able to manually view or list a zip file and gather the data is not possible. This could be considered a missing feature or just a limitation in general on how it works. You might request a better clarification over here:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106

Sadly it seems that Drive API is limited in a way that would require the unzip process as discussed directly in the community:

- [Google Script - How to use unzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48406765/google-script-how-to-use-unzip)

**References**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzip(BlobSource)
- [Is it possible to use the Google Drive API to get file from within a shared .zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68124064/is-it-possible-to-use-the-google-drive-api-to-get-file-from-within-a-shared-zip)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.  This is right along with what I was able to find.  Zipping and importing the files was done essentially just to improve the import speed.  I will likely try importing the image files without zipping and working to organize them after.